# Grid Tie Inverter Anti islanding

Tags: inverter, power-engineering, pll

I was wondering about anti islanding design.
Using grid tie inverters is usually the best choice when not investing in batteries, but suppose you have batteries and want the confort of grid tie AND get uninterruptible power in case of mains failure ?
if I understand well the current state of design and regulations for grid tie inverters is that anti islanding is compulsory.

Could it be designed better, for instance, in an islanding condition, the GTI could have a supplementary control bus to send a command to a relay / controllable breaker (something in this style :https://www.se.com/ww/en/product-range/60180-acti9-reflex-ic60) to isolate the domestic installation just after the power meter (on user side), plus a bus to sense when power returns between the breaker and the power meter.

When power returns, it can slowly regulate the inverter frequency to slowly bring back the phase into sync, lock it with PLL and switch back the controlled breaker / relay to tie to the grid.

I understand that it add complexity, and the need to sense the mains supply externally and control a breaker (which does not seem to be standardized when it comes to control, unless it is a simple relay), but some GTI already have external sensors or modules (like current sensors for GTI with limiters)

So, Why something this convenient is not yet marketed, (that would be hugely useful in California given the recent power cuts) ?

Is the problem the pulse generated by switching on the mains  ?

Comment: The problem is likely the regulatory aspect : proving to the standard required in your jurisdiction that even in the case of every possible malfunction of your design, it will not electrocute the linemen repairing your grid connection.

Comment: TECHNICALLY what you describe is entirely doable. The main drivers to making it happen are perhaps 1. There needs to be enough money in it for suppliers to push for it. 2. Enough people need to riot in the streets put up barricades and burn random cars to get enough attention to the fact that solar battery systems are stupidly dead in the water when the battery makes most sense of all. | Using eg Hong Kong as a model of the effectiveness of such actions in getting results - don't expect it any time soon. |

Comment: Simpler system: Accept initial outage. Manually decouple local island and manually connect to a local pseudo grid source. || eg Sunny Island inverters provide islanding systems but do not cross the divide.